# Get Outcome by Test Case ID

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm at a loss with this one. What is the most direct way I can get the outcome of a test run associated with a test case (work item)?

Here is the API call for [Get Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?api-version=5.0
```

I would need the runId and the testCaseResultId.

I can get a list of [test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0
```

but this doesn't seem to have any association with test cases.

There isn't much to do with the [Test Cases section of the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

I must be missing something, it shouldn't be this hard to get a result of a test case?

Comment: Did you already try using the detailsToInclude expand that includes workItems?

Comment: I did not try that yet. I would need to know the runId and the testCaseResultId of a given test case. There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that?